# convert MediaPlayer time to DataFormated

Tags: android

is there any way to convert durtion of MediaPlayer that is in long to String .

```
long is 500271 which equales 08:20
```

how can I convert this long to this type of formated text , also be careful that you may have hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "is" is your time in milliseconds

```
 long t=is/1000;
 int h=0;
int min=t/60;
  if(min>60)
 {
  h=min/60;
  min=min%60;
 }
 int sec=t%60;
 String time="time="h":"+min+":"+sec
```